# How to find out, whether a DOMElement/DOMNode is a subnode of a DOMDocument in PHP?

Tags: php, dom, domdocument, appendchild

I have a [`DOMElement`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php). How can I find out, wheter it is a subnode of a [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/de/class.domdocument.php)?

Background of the question:

> [A DOMElement object] is read only. It may be appended to a document,
>   but additional nodes may not be appended to this node until the node
>   is associated with a document. (see
>   [here](http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.construct.php)).

---

EDIT:

[`DOMNode#getNodePath()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.getnodepath.php) gets an XPath location path for the node. The root node has the path `/`. Ergo a node is a subelement, if its location is not equals to `/`.

But that works only for subnodes. If it's an "independent" node object, a warning is raised:

```
$test = new \DOMNode();
echo $test->getNodePath();
```

> Warning: DOMNode::getNodePath(): Couldn't fetch DOMNode in /path/too/foo.php on line 16

Answer (score 0):

You should check the `ownerDocument` property:

```
if ($node->ownerDocument === $document) {
    // $node is part of $document
} else {
    $importedNode = $document->importNode($node, true);
    // now you can append the node wherever you choose in the document
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Check the type of class it is:

```
if($dom instanceof \DOMDocument) { ... }
```